# Is it OK to hide Delphi's "Application" Window?

Tags: delphi

We just moved our application from a MDI container to a single document interface.  Our users are used to using a "Windows" menu in the MDI parent to show windows side by side.  We want to train them to right click on the Windows taskbar and use the window management functions there.

With Delphi applications we noticed that the windows shell leaves room for the hidden "Application" window.  So if I only have two windows open it will arrange room for three.  The Application window is not really shown but there is space left for it.

This is made worse by the fact that we have two different applications.  If they only have one window open in each application and want to show them side by side windows will actually try to account for 4 windows.

So instead of seeing two windows each taking 1/2 of the screen I see two windows that take up 1/4 of the desktop and the rest of the screen is open.

I found that adding a line to hide the application window as my application starts up will fix this problem.

<del>ShowWindow(Application.Handle, SW_HIDE);</del>

> Edit in case someone does not read
>   down to the answer.  Based on Craig's
>   answer below I am setting the windows
>   style to WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW instead of
>   hiding the window.
>         **SetWindowLong(Application.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE,
>           GetWindowLong(Application.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE) or WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW);**

My (original) questions is: Is this safe (hiding the application window)?  I'm wondering if I may be breaking something else by hiding the Application window.  Are there any side effect I need to be aware of?  Is there a better way to solve this issue?

I'm using Delphi 2007.  The issues seem to be consistent across Windows XP, Vista, and 7.

**Update:** Some of the answers seem to think the problem is with the Application forms icon being visible.  That is not the case.  I already have MainFormOnTaskbar set to true.

Also if you are testing this be aware that the Delphi IDE (only tested with 2007) makes things worse.  Try this.  Open the Delphi IDE and two instances of notepad.  Minimize the IDE but have both notepads un-minimized.  Right click on choose Show Windows Side by Side.  You will see each notepad take up 1/3 of the screen.  Close the IDE and choose Show Windows Side by Side again and each will take up 1/2 half of the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as MainFormOnTaskBar is true, you can fix the problem by adding this to your DPR:

```
SetWindowLong(Application.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE,
  GetWindowLong(Application.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE) or WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW);
```

Later versions of Delphi automatically include the `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` flag when they create the TApplication handle.

Comment: It's already off the taskbar.  The problem is getting Windows to ignore the window when auto-arranging the visible windows.

Comment: @Mark: Part of the code I linked to flags the application window as a tool window, which fixes the problem you're seeing.  I'm assuming they do something similar in later Delphis, since it isn't necessary in Delphi XE.

Comment: @Mark: See my edits;  I've verified the fix with Delphi 2007 and XP.

Comment: Works great.  Since this is what Delphi XE is doing seems reasonable for me to do this in my code.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In Delphi 2007 (and above) the Application Window does not show on TaskBar at all if

```
Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
```

line is in a project file (*.dpr). For example

```
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;   // <--
  Application.CreateForm(TForm7, Form7);
  Application.CreateForm(TForm8, Form8);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

That is default setting for new applications, but this line is absent if you ported an application from previous Delphi version - you should add this line manually.

Comment: My issue is not with the window being on the taskbar.  It is with the window being included in the arrange list.  I can take a default project with one form and set MainFormOnTaskbar to true.  Then run the exe twice, right click on the taskbar and choose "Show Windows Side by Side".  Each window will only take 1/4 of the screen instead of 1/2.

Comment: @Mark - Can't reproduce with Delphi 2009 - each window takes 1/2 of the screen as it should. The issue is specific to Delphi 2007 - and Craig's answer resolves it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still using Delphi 7, and I've been using this technique in combination with [the 'WndParent:=GetDesktopWindow' trick](http://yoy.be/item.asp?i89) to get a taskbar button for each window, somewhat like Microsoft Office started doing since some version (I guess XP?)

Comment: By this technique to you mean "ShowWindow(Application.Handle, SW_HIDE);"?

Comment: You should set WndParent to 0, not GetDesktopWindow.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/24/79212.aspx

Answer (score -1):

I believe at this is the way that applications minimize to the system tray.